# JIRA JQL Issues created between 5pm and midnight for an entire month

Tags: jira, jql

Does anyone know how to filter issues in a given project to show only issues that were created between 5pm and midnight for an entire month?

I am able to constrain between 5pm and midnight on a single day as below but am unsure how to make it do the whole month:

```
project = CI AND issuetype = "Activity" AND (created >= endOfDay('-1860m') AND created <= endOfDay(-1440m))
```

Comment: I know the equivalent SQL but not sure how it is done in JQL and could not find anything online. The SQL I am trying to run is:

Comment: Disregard the above comment. I know the equivalent SQL but not sure how it is done in JQL and could not find anything online. The SQL I am trying to run is: `SELECT *, TO_DATE(Created,'HH24') as created_hour FROM CI WHERE issuetype = "Activity" AND created_hour > 17 AND  created_hour <= 23 `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to write a JQL function using the GroovyRunner plugin in JIRA.
Am having some performance issues which I will put in another StackOverflow question

EDIT:
 Performance issue post available here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18606967/jira-jql-performance-issue-with-custom-function-in-groovyrunner